# Is it valid to set both page level setTargeting and slot level setTargeting in DFP gpt tag?

Tags: google-ad-manager

I want to use both Page level setTargeting and adSlot level Targeting in DFP gpt adtag.

Example:-

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/xxxxxxxx/xxxx.co.in/technology', [[728,90],[970,90],[970,250]], 'div-gpt-ad-1')
        .addService(googletag.pubads())
        .setTargeting('test',['refresh']);
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest(),
        googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(),
        googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering(),
        googletag.enableServices();

        googletag.pubads().setTargeting('interests', 'sports');

});
```

will both the target go to apply or only one?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. You can combine slot-level and page-level targeting.

Comment: I know, i can use both but which one will apply or both will apply.

Comment: Both. If you define the same key twice, I would guess that slot level would override page level. Need to test that though.